# What did I do wrong at the very beginning of "Your Second iOS App" by Apple?

Tags: ios, appsettings

as I am following the second of Apple's beginner-tutorials "Your second iOS App", it seems that I've made a mistake but I can't figure out where:

The tutorial I am referring to: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html

The very first step (the first blue point) is to create a new project. In the next steps this default project gets built & run but the Apple screenshots are different from mine :

http://www.screencast.com/users/PascalFritzen/folders/Jing/media/a9ae52f5-8d1c-4f5d-9156-cff752fe1f37

While trying to fix the problem I checked the option "Use Core Data" and the app looked like the Apple version. But later on the code of it also doesn't match with the tutorial :(

Thanks for reading & I hope someone can help me with this :)

Edit: maybe it helps to say that a few steps further in the tutorial one has to comment out the following lines of code ("Birds" is the creative prefix of the tutorial so don't wonder :) ):

```
import "BirdsMasterViewController.h"

/*

@interface BirdsMasterViewController () {

   NSMutableArray *_objects;

}

@end

*/

@implementation BirdsMasterViewController
```

Comment: In your UITableView's numberOfSections delegate method, is the number 0 or 1?

Comment: "1" and the Content is set to "Static Cells", not to "Dynamic Prototypes" as it should be (?)

Comment: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section?

You need to post code.

Comment: I would check if your array is initialized.

Comment: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

Comment: I would take a look at that tutorial again, your code makes no sense....

Comment: I should have mentioned that I haven't done **any** coding so far. It's only about **creating** a project (with the specific options mentioned in the very first step of the tutorial) - and since that leads to a wrong view (see the picture link above) and wrong generated code (see the code that I should comment out but that doesn't exist) I'm confused - but again, I haven't done any coding yet to rule that out as an error source :/ Thank you anyway, @CodaFi , for your help so far :))

Comment: well, I manually downloaded the latest version of Xcode (I "checked for updates" about 5 times) and it seems to work now :/ my bad, thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is answered :) I did not use the current version of Xcode (instead i used the default version that was shipped)